# Problem with a shorter solution

Tags: checkmate, problems

I'm looking at [this problem](https://gameknot.com/chess-puzzle.pl?pz=238406).

```
[Title "White to move. Mate in three"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "5rb1/1p1P1pbr/1p5p/5N/PP2k/1Np3QB/6K/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

It requires white to mate in three. The accepted solution starts with 1. Kf1. But there seems to be a mate in 2 via 1. Ne7 and then 2. Bf5.

Am I missing something? If the mate in 2 is correct, is it common/normal for a problem to request a mate in 3 when a mate in 2 is available?

Comment: This problem is from the book "200 ausgewählte Schachaufgaben von O. Fuss und F. Möller, 1939" and is correct (computer tested, WinChloe ID=220207), keymove 1.Kf1!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After 1.Ne7 Black has 1...f5, stopping the immediate 2.Bf5#.

Comment: It had to be something simple. Thanks a lot!